# No Launcher Activity found with .Launcher in Manifest.xml already included?

Tags: android, filter, android-emulator, android-intent

I am trying to run a source code I've found online for android. When I run it, it gives me:

> No Launcher activity found!
>   The launch will only sync the application package on the device!
>   Performing sync

I already have in my Manifest.xml the following:

```
action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" 
category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"
```

What could be wrong? The weird thing is that it worked once. And then when I ran it again it gave me needs to force the application.

It is not a duplicate question because I've read that everyone is suggesting to place those in the Manifest.xml.

Comment: Please post the entire Manifest.xml file

Comment: Another solution would be to go to: "Run -> Run Configurations -> then choose the activity you want to launch (its name is explicitly mentioned below the default activity"

hope this helps anyone facing a similar problem!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I think you need to define a launching activity. For example in my app

```
    <activity android:name=".Main"
              android:label="@string/app_name">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

I have defined which activity is started on app start.

Comment: Ok it worked ! yes the default activity was not working..i had to explicitly mention the name of the activity in the manifest.xml

Answer (score 0):

please make sur to add `android:exported="true"` it will be like that

```
<activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Comment: that means that this activity is accessible and can be launched from an external application.