# Launching App on my phone from Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse, cordova, android-emulator

When i try to run my phone gap test app. I get this error below. I have my phone plugged into the computer and debugging is turned on.
Does the error below mean my phone is not running the correct android version? I have a Htc Evo running android 4 something.

My project is set for android 4.1.2.

"No active compatible AVD's or devices found. Relaunch this configuration after connecting a device or starting an AVD."

What am i doing wrong to get this to debug on my phone?
Or how do i set up the enumerator to run the app on my PC?

Thanks

Comment: Install adb drivers for your phone, turn debugging on from `settings > development` and then eclipse should be able to launch the application onto your phone.

Comment: Thanks that worked. I no longer get that error but it still doesn not load on my device. I get this 30 09:04:13 - Testing] No Launcher activity found!
[2012-10-30 09:04:13 - Testing] The launch will only sync the application package on the device!

Comment: In your `applicationmanifest`, you need to declare one of the activities as your launcher.

Comment: <application
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
         android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale"
        
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_main" >
            <meta-data
                android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
                android:value="MainActivity" />
        </activity>
    </application>

Comment: Its it declaired there? Thats from my Androidmanifest.xml

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/a/6181148/759019. That is how you declare the launcher thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In DDMS Device pane if your device is visible then you have drivers otherwise install drivers. If you have your device there in the devices pane still you you getting this then check your minimum sdk version in application. If that is lower than your device. Then delete .android folder from your home folder after closing the eclipse and start that again.

Comment: `delete .android folder `. I think that step is unncessary.

Answer (score 2):

You need to have the HTC Drivers installed on your computer to see the device. You should be able to find them at HTC's site.

Edit: If they don't have the driver file itself for download, you can download the HTC Sync and begin to install that. The first step of installing that will install the drivers, if you watch you can just cancel the installation after that so you just have the drivers. It may be a large file to download for just the drivers, but at least you know the file is coming from HTC.